# Facebook publish_actions deprecated: Upload a photo

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

We have an ElectronJS program where we'd like people to be able to take a photo and upload to facebook. However, after reading facebook's documentation, they have removed the publish_actions permission.

Further reading of Facebook's documentation makes reference to using their graph api sharing (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog).

However, it's not exactly clear as to whether or not a photo can be uploaded or the only option is to be shared as a link?

I was hoping to get some clarification, now that they've removed the publish_actions, what now essentially?

Alternatively, are there any other solutions?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only share URLs, there is no uploading via the dialogs.

You will need to upload this photo to your own server first, and then create a URL that returns the appropriate OG meta tags, including the one for the image you want to use as thumbnail. (You could also share the image URL directly, but that usually doesn’t look very nice.)

Comment: Hi misorude, yes after posting this, I was thinking that uploading to our server may be our only option. Thanks for the clarification. Cheers.